# Excel Array to Determine Conflicts of Segregation of Duties

Tags: arrays, excel

I have two lists; the first is a list of segregation of duty conflicts based upon a specific ability (e.g. approver can't be a requester or receiver of purchase orders). An ability may have many conflicts with other abilities and an employee may have multiple abilities. The goal is to compare whether each employee's abilities matches a SOD conflict from each, 1 column at a time (SOD Conflict 1 matches Conflict 1 and as does SOD Conflict 2 matches Conflict 2). It's very important that the employee's name/id is looped back to see if following instances of that specific name/id present a conflict for the previous name. That way all employees' abilities are being calculated.

Currently I have the below fomula that only displays CONFLICT if the instance is the top row of my Segregation of Duty Conflict table.

```
{=IF(($A$2:$A$7=$A11)*($B$12:$B$17=$B11)*($A12:$A$17=B$2:B$7),"CONFLICT","")}
```

Can you help me with the formula so I can drag it down the list of the employee abilities to determine if a conflict exists beyond the first instance? Brownie points if you can have the segregation of duty conflict listed :) TIA. FYI, my VBA skills are nonexistent concurrently, but I'm all ears for learning just ELI5 it please if you venture that path.

Here's a link to the completed file using Google Docs...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kzFB1qfARoqK53ZFeEXRjuHQMN00Fs3quL6Jc73NPqQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
   A             B               C              D           E
1  Type          SOD Confict 1   SOD Confict 2
2  PO request    Test            Test       
3  PO approval   PO request      PO receive     
4  PO receiv     PO request      PO approval        
5  PO Purchase   Test            PO Test 2      
6  PO Placement  Test 3          PO Test 4      
7  Test          PO Test 5       PO Test 6      
8               
9               
10 Ability       Person          Employee ID    Conflict 1  Conflict 2
11 PO request    John            1              CONFLICT    CONFLICT
12 Test          John            1      
13 PO receive    John            1      
14 PO receive    Jake            2      
15 PO request    Jake            2      
16 PO approval   Jimmy           3      
17 PO receive    Jimmy           3
```

Comment: Include links to the pictures in your post and someone (maybe me) will edit them in.  Also can you clean up those tables [using this website/tool](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) and the tables using the code block entry (select text and then CTRL+K).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions which I've updated for. If there's more that I can do to clarify, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Complete revision.

Consider this screenshot.

[image]

D11 and E11 return empty cells.

D12: "Test" is a 'SOD Conflict 1`in rows 2 and 5. In these cases, column A has the values`PO request', which matches John's first ability in A11. Hence `PO request` is a conflict. The same goes for E12.

D13: `PO receive` in A13 is not a `SOD Conflict 1`. Case closed.

E13: `PO receive` in A13 is found in `SOD Conflict 2` in row 3. In column A of that row, `PO approval` does not match with John's first ability in A11. No conflict.

D15: `PO request` in A15 is found in `SOD Conflict 1`, and the value in A4 matches Jake's first ability `PO receive`, so the conflict is `PO receive`. E15 is blank because `PO request` is not a `SOD Conflict 2`.

D17: Jimmy's `PO receive` is not a `SOD Conflict 1`, so the cell is blank.

E17: `PO receive` is found in `SOD conflict 2` and the corresponding value in A3 is `PO approval` which is Jimmy's first ability. Hence a conflict with `PO approval`.

The formula in D11 is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,SUMPRODUCT((B$2:B$7=$A11)*(($A$2:$A$7=INDEX($A$11:$A$30,MATCH($B11,$B$11:$B$30,0)))*ROW($A$1:$A$6)))),"")
```

It's not an array formula. Copy across to E11 and down.

Comment: Yes, John's second ability, test, also matches in B2:B7 for his first ability, PO Request. The document I sent contains the formula that works only for the first ability and states "CONFLICT". However, his 3rd ability in cell D13 should state "CONFLICT" as well.

Any ability a person has from A11:A17 needs to be matched to A1:7 and then determined if any of that person's abilities from A11:A17 is on the same line in Column B as A2:A7. The whole point is to make sure a person who can approve a purchase order can't also request a purchase order or receive.

Comment: You really need to work on specifying your requirements. That last sentence, where you put in plain words what you are trying to achieve, is a thousand times better than attempts to refer to formulas and ranges. I edited my answer to a different approach.

Comment: Third time lucky. I put in a new approach. See if that fits. By the way, it would have helped ***IMMENSELY*** if you had mocked up the expected result with explanations of each case, just like I've done above.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I've updated my speadsheet to include expected conflict and the results of your formula as well as whether the two matched. It's not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to the completed file using Google Docs...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kzFB1qfARoqK53ZFeEXRjuHQMN00Fs3quL6Jc73NPqQ/edit?usp=sharing

I ended up using a nested vlookup in a vlookup to a range where I concantenated employee ID and ability so there would only be 1 unique item irregardless to avoid arrays. Perhaps a bit dirtier, but solved the problem.